# Android 2.1 Detect Bluetooth audio connect/disconnect

Tags: android, bluetooth, playback

I'm scratching my head trying to find a way to detect bluetooth headset connect and disconnect events for Android 2.1. I see in API Level 11 that there are some explicit ones, but how do I do it in API level 7? I just want to know when the user connects or disconnects a headset or car stereo capable of playing audio, so that I can pause the sounds I'm playing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no public APIs, 
This [answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020421/problem-invoking-a-private-unpublished-method-in-android-api) where the author used private APIs using reflections.

The author has also posted a comment on how he got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED) looks like a good option to detect bluetooth connect/disconnect.

If that didn't work, another good option is to set a timer in a service that calls `AudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn()` to check if the bluetooth is connected or disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works in 2.1, but it works in 2.2 and 2.3.

It will capture Bluetooth-Headset connection state changes:

Declare the following intent-filter

```
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and in your Receiver in onReceive check for:

```
if ("android.bluetooth.headset.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
  headsetAudioState = intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.headset.extra.AUDIO_STATE", -2);
}
```

and save the int as a static variable. Access it anytime you want to know if BT audio is connected(1) / disconnected(0). Not pretty, but gets the job done.

Also check out:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.java

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.bluetooth.headset.action.STATE_CHANGED` action. The Intent's extra `android.bluetooth.headset.extra.STATE` contains current state (disconnected, connecting, connected). More info the [Android source code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/frameworks/base/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.java)